# Unity Shader Graph Dissolve on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, game-engine

I'm working on a mobile game, and i wanted to create a shader, using the shader graph, to dissolve a part of mesh, when a collider interacts with it (see example below).

[image]

Is it possible to do it with shader Graph? because i don't know how to write shaders.

Thank you!

Comment: An [intersection shader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwo3AHzagvg)  would be a good point to start, but it looks like it might not be achievable using shader graph [yet](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/9sx4ux/how_to_do_a_intersect_effect_in_shader_graph/).

Comment: I came up with a dissolve shader, but i have issues to link it to a intersection line.